# Axiom of Choice equivalence: is my proof correct?

Tags: proof-writing, set-theory, axiom-of-choice

I'm trying to prove the equivalence between two different statements of the Axiom of Choice (presented below as **AC1** and **AC2**). I'd like to know if my proof is correct (also presented below).

One concern I have is the following: is it necessary to prove that the set $\{B_i\}_{i\in I}$ (as described in the proof below) can be defined? And if this is the case, did I prove that point correctly?

Another concern I have is about the converse proof: can I just assume that the range of a given function is a set that exists, or do I need to specify that I'm applying the axiom of replacement to get such set?

Aside from these concerns, I'm also open to any other correction and suggestion you'd like to give. Thank you everybody in advance.

---

**AC1**. *Let $I$ be a non-empty set, and let $\{S_i\}_{i\in I}$ be a pairwise disjoint family of non-empty sets indexed by $I$. There exists a set $C$ such that $|C\cap S_i|=1$ for all $i\in I$. Such set is called the **choice set***.

**AC2**. *Let $I$ be a non-empty set, and let $\{S_i\}_{i\in I}$ be a family of non-empty sets indexed by $I$. There is function $f:I\to\bigcup_{i\in I}S_i$ such that $f(i)\in S_i$ for all $i\in I$. Such function is called the **choice function***.

**Proof of the equivalence between AC1 and AC2**:

($\Rightarrow$) Let $I$ be a non-empty set, and let $\{A_i\}_{i\in I}$ be a family of non-empty sets which is not necessarily pairwise disjoint. Since $I$ is a non-empty set and since every set $A_i$ is non-empty, the corresponding set $\{i\}\times A_i=\{(i,x):x\in A_i\}$ is also non-empty. So, the family of non-empty sets $\{B_i\}_{i\in I}$, in which $B_i=\{i\}\times A_i$ for every $i\in I$, can be defined.

It can be shown by contradiction that $\{B_i\}_{i\in I}$ is pairwise disjoint. Suppose that there exist two indices $p,q\in I$ such that $p\neq q$ and $B_p\cap B_q\neq\emptyset$. This implies that there exists an ordered pair $(x,y)$ such that $(x,y)\in B_p\cap B_q$. But then, it would be the case that $p=x=q$, which contradicts the assumption that $p\neq q$, so no such indices exist.

Now that it's been shown that $\{B_i\}_{i\in I}$ is a pairwise disjoint family of non-empty sets, **AC1** can be applied to obtain the set $C$. This set is a subset of $I\times\bigcup_{i\in I} A_i$. Also, for every $(j,x)\in C$, it is the case that $j\in I$ and $x\in A_i$, and that there is no $(j',x')\in C$ for which $j=j'$ and $x\neq x'$. Thus, there exists a choice function for $\{A_i\}_{i\in I}$ that is defined by $C$.

($\Leftarrow$) Now, let $\{A_i\}_{i\in I}$ be pairwise disjoint. **AC2** can be applied to obtain the choice function $f:I\to\bigcup_{i\in I}A_i$. Let $C$ be the range of $f$. Since $\{A_i\}_{i\in I}$ is pairwise disjoint, it follows that $|C\cap S_i|=1$ for all $i\in I$. Thus, $C$ is the choice set for $\{A_i\}_{i\in I}$.

Comment: It is all correct but (at the level you are writing the proof) it's worth explaining why $|C \cap A_i| = 1$ for all $i \in I$. On one hand, $|C \cap A_i| \geq 1$ since for each $i$, we know at least one element (namely, $f(i)$) is in the intersection. If we have $x,y \in C \cap A_i$, then $x,y \in C$ implies $x = f(j)$ and $y = f(k)$, for some $j,k \in I$. But then $x \in A_j$ and $y \in A_k$, so now the fact $\{A_i\}_{i\in I}$ is pairwise disjoint forces $j = i =k$, as desired.

Comment: Thanks for the correction. One question: can I safely assume that the range of the function $f$, mentioned in the last paragraph of exists? I was thinking that maybe I need to state that I'm using the axiom of replacement.

Comment: Yes, absolutely. That follows from the definition of $f$ being a function.